# How can I read cereal serialized data from C++ using Python

Tags: python, c++, serialization, ros, cereal

I'm using rospy and roscpp to connect each other. One of the roscpp node published a cereal binary archive topic and is subscribed by rospy node. How can I read the cereal binary archive using python？

Comment: Without more information it's really hard to understand and answer your question. But you may should have a look at https://github.com/jcarbaugh/cereal .

Comment: Do you have to use cereal?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you're trying to send a message between ros nodes, that happen to be implemented in different languages. But the language of implementation doesn't matter, because ros automatically serializes the messages. Fundamentally, all it is is a language-agnostic messaging system. If you want to pass data between nodes, choose a message type, publish that message to a topic in one node, and subscribe to it with a callback in another node.

If you want to use a custom serialization over data, and the ros messages seem insufficient, then you probably want to use a [std_msgs::](http://docs.ros.org/api/std_msgs/html/index-msg.html) [String!](http://docs.ros.org/api/std_msgs/html/msg/String.html), [ByteMultiArray](http://docs.ros.org/api/std_msgs/html/msg/ByteMultiArray.html), or [UInt8MultiArray](http://docs.ros.org/api/std_msgs/html/msg/UInt8MultiArray.html). But cereal doesn't quite do automatic serialization for you, as you still have to declare the functions. Overall, if you're using ros, it seems redundant; unless you're using it, perhaps, to log or store data?